# Issue with the return type of the `get_mpz_t` function of GNU MP

Tags: c++, gmp

The GNU MP manual [specifies](https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-General) the declaration of the function `get_mpz_t`:

```
Function: mpz_t mpz_class::get_mpz_t ()
```

So I was expecting a `mpz_t` return type. But running the simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>
using namespace std;

int main (void) {
    mpz_class n;
    n = "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
    mpz_t m;
    mpz_init(m);
    m = n.get_mpz_t();
    gmp_printf("m %Zd\n", m);
}
```

Compiled with

```
g++ mpz_test.cc -o mpz_test -lgmpxx -lgmp
```

Produces the error output at line `m = n.get_mpz_t()`:

```
mpz_split.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
mpz_split.cc:12:4: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘mpz_ptr {aka __mpz_struct*}’ to ‘mpz_t {aka __mpz_struct [1]}’
  m = n.get_mpz_t();
    ^
```

Looking at the `gmpxx.h` code I find the declarations:

```
// conversion functions
mpz_srcptr __get_mp() const { return mp; }
mpz_ptr __get_mp() { return mp; }
mpz_srcptr get_mpz_t() const { return mp; }
mpz_ptr get_mpz_t() { return mp; }
```

And, of course, `mpz_ptr` is defined in `gmp.h`

```
typedef __mpz_struct *mpz_ptr;
```

So, is the manual inaccurate? Or, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: mpz_t is an array type, you cannot assign arrays in C++.

Comment: Wow, Marc that was really *fast*! Thanks a lot for the remeinder on C++, but then if I use `m[1]` on all lines it also does not work. I understand defining `typedef __mpz_struct mpz_t[1]` has its advantages for C, but now this seem as a disadvantage for C++. Can you please hint to a simple solution?

Comment: `gmp_printf("m %Zd\n", n.get_mpz_t());`

Comment: Ok, thanks, but I really would like to have it on a `mpz_t` variable to make other operations, is there's a way, perhaps working directly on `mpz_ptr` types?

Comment: Then use `mpz_ptr` if that's what you want...

Comment: Well, I guess that's the option to go with... I would perhaps suggest some update to the manual, but, anyways, thanks again Marc.

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs on this line:

```
m = n.get_mpz_t();
```

You cannot assign to `mpz_t` directly, instead use `mpz_set()`:

```
mpz_set(m, n.get_mpz_t());
```

So, your code should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>
using namespace std;

int main (void) {
    mpz_class n;
    n = "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
    mpz_t m;
    mpz_init(m);
    mpz_set(m, n.get_mpz_t()); // correct assignment
    gmp_printf("m %Zd\n", m);
}
```